Is it OK to use the word "anytime" as a conjunction?
I just want to know if "anytime" is the correct answer in this example.
Here: Anytime I want to relax, I just step outside and breathe the fresh air.
I was taking the quiz in this article when I saw this question.
https://www.dictionary.com/e/anytime-vs-any-time/
I answered "anytime" and it was incorrect. Now, I'm wondering why it is incorrect because from what I've learned in this article https://www.grammarly.com/blog/anytime-any-time/ as a conjunction, either is correct but in the example I've provided here, "anytime" is wrong.
I've also seen another example in this article https://prowritingaid.com/any-time-vs-anytime that used "any time" as a conjunction. I am also wondering if "anytime" here is correct.
Here: "Any time I see an old-fashioned teaspoon, I buy it for my nan who collects them."
These examples caused me some confusion and I hope someone here can help me. Thanks in advance!

I would not use anytime as a single word. The last link describes it as modern usage, so that no doubt reflects my age! The same link also says that any time will be correct in all contexts, but not anytime. So the important lesson for English learners may be to start with any time, the two word phrase.

I see no difference between the sentence in the quiz and this one from the list of examples: "Anytime I see Kate, she’s reading a book." In any case, this is the kind of distinction that is so small that an error would probably not get caught in the publication process until it reaches the copyeditor.

As a single word, "anytime" can be an adjective or an adverb:

"It's an anytime kind of shirt." (suitable for all occasions).
"Drop by anytime." (whenever you feel like it).

As two words, "any time" is a noun:

"Will you have any time to work on the project this afternoon?"

It's similar to "every day" (noun or adverb) and "everyday" (adjective).

The issue is that any time is two words, not one word. That's probably why it's coming back as incorrect.
